# having issues calling a sql stored procedure, SelectById, from express

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a saved stored procedure from SQL in my node app. my server is connected and I am able to execute my selectRandom5 saved proc with no problems.

the issue I am having is when I try to do a getById where I need to declare the @Id input. I've tried a couple of variations of the function with no luck, here are two I've tried.

the error message I get with this is UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '?'.

```
selectById(req, res) {
    var theId = req.params.id;

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query("CALL Addresses_SelectById(?)", [theId], function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log("connect", err);

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            console.log(recordset);
        });
    });
}
```

and then there's this other function I've tried, and the error message I get from this is 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Id".'

```
 selectById(req, res) {
    var theId = req.params.id;

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query(`SET @Id = ${theId}CALL Addresses_SelectById(@Id)`, function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log("connect", err);

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            console.log(recordset);
        });
    });
}
```

I just want to be able to pass parameters to SQL to be able to create update or get by but so far I haven't been able to figure out the proper way to pass the parameters.

any help would be appreciated! thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND IT GUYS!

selectById(req, res) {
var theId = req.params.id;

```
    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.input("Id", sql.Int, theId);
        request.execute("Addresses_SelectById", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log("connect", err);

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            console.log(recordset);
        });
    });
```

I changed it to this and it works

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

Suggested alternate syntax:

```
selectById(req, res) {
    var theId = req.params.id;

    let sql = `CALL Addresses_SelectById(?)`;
    connection.query(sql, theId, (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.error(error.message);
      }
      console.log(results[0]);
      // Possibly stringify "results" to JSON before sending...
      res.send(results);
    });
}
```